# Couchbase DocumentSize affecting View-Visibility?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I'm trying to save some larger files (0.1 - 10MB, Images) in Couchbase.
Dimensions from 128x128 up to 4096x4096.
My problem now is:

I am not able to get the *keys* of larger files in a *View*.
They are simply missing even in the Couchbase-Console and with *stale=false*

View-Code is simply (show me all the keys):

```
function(doc, meta){
  emit(meta.id, null)
}
```

I was able to narrow down:

- The key-Name is irrelevant
- The "DataBuckets" -> "Documents" shows all the entries in the CouchbaseConsole
- All Files are accessible with the key directly
- The File-Type does not seem to matter (jpg,png,bmp)
- The **File-Size** matters.
- Somewhere between 2300 KB and 2800 KB the Indexing changes. Smaller Documents are included, bigger ones are no longer included in the View (in the Documents-Tab they are visible in the CouchbaseConsole)

I was unable to find anything about this in the documentation or somewhere else. Just a 20MB soft-maximum filesize is mentioned. Am I missing something? Deleting several entries without the ability to use views gets kinda complicated.

> You are running version 2.5.1 enterprise edition (build-1083)

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24812549/92516

Comment: Thanks, i can rule those two out. Both are exactly at 1 MB in the default.ini and i have docs in the view above 1 MB